# How can I solve a pde with second derivative boundary condition?

Tags: matlab, method-of-lines

I have an equation like

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} =A\frac{\partial^4u}{\partial x^4} $$

with boundary condition $$ u(x = \pm L,t) = 9; u_{xx} (x=\pm L,t) = 4 $$

I tried to use the method of lines and rewrote the whole PDE equation in the form of

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = A \frac{ u_{i+2} - 4u_{i+1} + 6u_{i} - 4u_{i-1} + u_{i-2}}{\Delta x^4} $$

But I am not sure how to apply a second derivative boundary condition in the equation. I did something like the below code and I know it is completely wrong because I didn't get the proper result when I used ode15s solver. What should I do for the second derivative boundary condition to be applied here?

```
tspan = [0 10];
N = 10;
u0(1) = 9; u0(N+1) = 9;
u0(2:N) = 0.8;

[tsol,usol] = ode15s(@pde_2D, tspan, u0);
plot(tsol,usol);

function dudt = pde_2D(t,x)
u0 = 9;
N = length(x)+1; deltax = 1/N;
u(1) = u0; u(N+1) = u0;
u(2:N) = x;
A = 1/2;

dudt1 = zeros(N+1,1);
for k = 2:N
    if k == 2 || k == N
        dudt1 (k) = (4*deltax^2) + (2*u(k) - u(k-1));
    else
        dudt1 (k) = (A/(deltax^4))*(u(k+2) - 4*u(k+1) + 6*u(k) - 4*u(k-1) + u(k-2));
    end
end
dudt = dudt1(2:N);
end
```

Comment: Boundary conditions are what makes the plate equation so difficult. Have you read about boundary conditions, what they mean physically, and how they are usually handled for this equation?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth yes I have been reading about Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions but all I have dealt with is just the first derivative so far. This is the first time I have come across a second derivative at boundaries

Comment: You can try toreduce the order of your PDE by introducing a new variable $v =\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 x}$. Then you will have two PDE's of lower order, for which the boundary conditions may be easier to handle.

Comment: @MPIchael I tried to reduce the second derivative into the central difference method again and I updated the code now. But it still doesn't work and I get a warning like "Unable to meet integration tolerances without reducing the step size"

Answer (score 4):

I have ignored your $A$ for the moment, you will need to perform the necessary modifications yourself to take it into account. In the below $L$ is just the matrix arising from $\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}$. Note that in your discretisation:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -4 & 6 & -4 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 1\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus a discretisation of $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ consistent with your discretisation of $\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}$ is:

$$\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}\right)(x_i) = \frac{u_{i-1} -2u_i + u_{i+1}}{h^2} + O(h^2).$$

Let $u_n=u(L)=9$. Your second partial derivative constraint at $x=L$ reads: $$\frac{u_{n-1} - 2u_n + u_{n+1}}{h^2} = 4.$$

Then knowing $u_n=9$ you are left with two unknowns: $u_{n-1}$ and $u_{n+1}$. One way to deal with this is by modifying your matrix-vector multiplication. First you will have to extend your vector with a cell $u_{n+1}$, then whenever you need to compute $y = Lx$ you can do a pre-step:

$$x_{n+1} = 4h^2+18-x_{n-1}.$$

Then you perform the multiplication as usual. The rightmost evaluation of your $\frac{\partial^4}{\partial x^4}$ approximation happens at $y_{n-1}$ and it involves $x_{n-3}, \, x_{n-2}, \, x_{n-1}, \, x_{n}, \, x_{n+1}$ and you know both $x_n = 9$ and $x_{n+1}$ from the above pre-step. You can do the exactly same thing for $u_1 = u(-L) = 9$ and you get:

$$x_{0} = 4h^2 + 18 - x_{2}.$$

This ultimately means that your vector $x$ should be 2 elements longer, one in the beginning corresponding to $x_{0}$ and another at the end corresponding to $x_{n+1}$, your Dirichlet BCs are then at $x_1$ and $x_n$. By applying the above you can apply your stencil unchanged when performing $Lx$ (it has the additional benefit that you do not need a special code path for the boundaries provided you do the prestep). Otherwise you would have to modify your stencil near the boundaries to do exactly the same thing as the procedure above.

If $A$ is a constant then afaik your step size in an explicit scheme should be $\tau<\frac{h^2}{8A}$. You can also try to solve the problem in a time-implicit manner:

$$\frac{u-u^0}{T} = A\frac{\partial^4 u}{\partial x^4}, \, u(t, \pm L) = 9, \, u_{xx}(t, \pm L) = 4$$

where $u^0$ is the initial state and $T$ is the time at which you want the solution. The above can be solved using an implicit scheme, so no constraint on the time step size. For example you can apply conjugate gradients to solve it.

Edit:

Regarding the form of $L$, a PDE of the form:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \alpha \frac{\partial^4u}{\partial x^4},$$

results in a linear system upon discretisation ($\boldsymbol{u}^k\in\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ being the solution at time $k\tau$):

$$\frac{u^{k+1}_i - u^k_i}{\tau} = \alpha\frac{u^k_{i-2}-4u^k_{i-1}+6u^k_i-4u^k_{i+1}+u^k_{i+2}}{h^2},\, i=2\ldots,n-1.$$
$$\implies$$
$$u^{k+1}_i = \frac{\tau\alpha}{h^2}\begin{bmatrix}1 & -4 & (\frac{h^2}{\tau\alpha}+6) & -4 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} u^k_{i-2} & u^k_{i-1} & u^k_i & u^k_{i+1} & u^k_{i+2} \end{bmatrix}^T$$

Once you add the boundary conditions you have additionally:

$$u^k_1 = 9, \, u^k_n = 9$$
$$u^k_0 = 4h^2+18-u^k_2, \, u^k_{n+1} = 4h^2+18-u^k_{n-1}$$

If you plug those in for the expressions for $u^{k+1}_2, \, u^{k+1}_3, \, u^{k+1}_{n-2}, \, u^{k+1}_{n-1}$ in order to eliminate the $u_0, \, u_1, \, u_{n}, \, u_{n+1}$ variables then you will get modified versions of $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -4 & (\frac{h^2}{\tau\alpha}+6) & -4 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ near the boundaries, but the whole thing will remain linear. This results in $n-2$ linear equations:

$$u^{k+1}_i = L_i \boldsymbol{u}^k, \, i=2,\ldots,n-1 \implies \boldsymbol{u}^{k+1} = L\boldsymbol{u}^k$$

where $L_i$ are the rows of $L$, formed by the stencils discussed above (padded with zeroes in order to correspond to the correct indices). In an iterative solver you need to be able to evaluate the matrix-vector product $\boldsymbol{y}=L\boldsymbol{x}$. This can be implemented even without explicitly constructing $\boldsymbol{L}$ and without modifying the stencil near the boundaries provided you add the extra elements $x_0,\, x_1, x_n, \, x_{n+1}$ and treat them as discussed.

Comment: I see that you have written $ y = Lx $ formula. But what is L here? How do you find this?

Comment: @dazemood I edited my answer to give details on how $L$ may be constructed. Usually you do not want to explicitly construct $L$ however. I was referring to $L\boldsymbol{x}$ just as a shorthand for the application of the outlined procedure. Also I just noticed that your boundaries in the continuous setting were also called $L$. Sorry if that caused any confusion. In the discretised setting with $L$ I am referring to the system matrix.